# Cannot create Shotwell slideshow after deleting previous slideshow

Tags: shotwell, slideshow

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I created a Shotwell slideshow and then decided I wanted to add more pictures.  I couldn't figure out how to edit the slide show so I deleted the images and xml file from the Shotwell wallpaper folder.  This got rid of the slideshow but now I can't seem to create a new one as the option to "Set as Desktop slideshow..." is greyed out in the Shotwell File menu. Should I just uninstall and reinstall Shotwell?  Seems like there should be a better way to handle slideshows, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You can try just reinstalling it. No need to go through the steps to remove it first. `apt-get --reinstall install shotwell` I don't guarantee that that fixes your problem, but that's how you can reinstall it. If you want to remove it and remove all the config files, that's what `purge` is for.

Comment: I reinstalled Shotwell, that did not help.  I then removed and purged it and reinstalled it and I still cannot create a slide show.  I'm scratching my head now.

Comment: I'm not a shotwell user. I tried to recreate it but I can't figure out what you deleted - and I'm not even sure how to make a slide show with it. I use something called "XNView MP" that is a closed source (but free as in cost) image app that I was pretty happy to see get ported to work with Linux. There's even a handy .deb available and it makes all the slide shows you could ever want.

Comment: I deleted the files in the ~/.local/share/shotwell/wallpaper folder. There were image files and a .xml file folder, now the folder is empty.

Comment: I have `/home/kgiii/.local/share/shotwell/data` and inside there is a `photo.db` and a backup file of said photo.db. There's nothing else in said /shotwell directory. When opened with a text editor, the entirety is just `SQLite format 3`. I *highly* doubt it'll work, but you could try recreating it.

Comment: I think the wallpaper folder was created the first time I added a slideshow with shotwell.  The last time I uninstalled and purged shotwell, then reinstalled shotwell the wallpaper folder was gone

Comment: I upgraded my system today (Aug. 26, 2020) and the problem resolved itself!

Comment: You  could write that up as an answer, though it'd be fairly vague and I'm not sure how useful it'd be to future searchers. Either way, glad it's sorted!

Comment: After encountering the same problem again I realized the problem.  If one (or more) of the selections is a video instead of a photo you cannot create the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

All selections must be photos, if you accidentally select a video it will not work.